# @BusinessProcessScoped bean and JSF 2 rendered attribute

Tags: jsf, cdi, activiti

when the form is submitted in JSF2 and I use the scope of the bean as @BusinessProcessScoped
value of bean is not updated in the action method. If I remove the rendered condition from panelGrid the values are updated. Could some one clarify whats the issue

Answer (score 0):

The `rendered` attribute must be evaluating to false. Even if it evaluates to true when the panel is rendered, it must be evaluating to false when you submit the data.

Debug or log the state of your model beans when the request is submitted to determine the cause of the problem.

---

Note that:

- the `rendered` attribute of a container also applies to the container's children
- the `rendered` attribute is not just used during the render response phase

For example, the functionality for reading data from the submitted data is performed by [the `processDecodes` method](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#processDecodes%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) which says:

> Perform the component tree processing required by the Apply Request
>   Values phase of the request processing lifecycle for all facets of
>   this component, all children of this component, and this component
>   itself, as follows.
>
> - **If the `rendered` property of this UIComponent is false, skip further processing.**
> - *...other instructions elided...*